# How to use 'compression_encode_buffer' in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-compression

I am using the compression library of Swift to compress an image as NSData.
This is the code:

```
var imageCompressed:NSData
compression_encode_buffer( imageCompressed ,800000 , imageSelected , size , NULL , COMPRESSION_LZMA )
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Cannot convert value of type NSData to expected argument  type UnsafeMutablePointer

Comment: You cannot write into an NSData. It is immutable!

Comment: Also - are you still using Swift 2???

Comment: Also, this is not a good algorithm to compress an image. Use JPEG, PNG or HEIF depending on needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like this (`imageSelected` and `imageCompressed` are assumed to be Swift 3 Data objects):

```
imageSelected.withUnsafeBytes {(fromBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    imageCompressed.withUnsafeMutableBytes {(toBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
        compression_encode_buffer(toBytes, toSize, fromBytes, fromSize, nil, COMPRESSION_LZMA)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the parameters of compression_encode_buffer ?

Comment: That would be another question. I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Yeah but what is toBytes , toSIze , fromBytes , fromSize?

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: `withUnsafeBytes` calles a closure which you specify and it passes in the pointer to the raw data buffer for the image (which you are at liberty to typecast to whatever, e.g UInt8). Then in the closure you work with the buffer.  Here he's nested two calls. `fromBytes` is the source image data. `toBytes` is the destination buffer (you need something like `var imageCompressed = Data(capacity:MAX_COMPRESSED_SIZE)` first). `fromSize` is the image buffer size in bytes and `toSize` is the `imageCompressed` buffer size (must be >= the amount needed for compression)

Answer (score 1):

As Matt has said you cannot write to an NSData object, because it is immutable. I strongly recommend that you use Swift Standard Library `Data` type instead. Then you could call `withUnsafeMutableBytes` and do what you want inside its closure.